# How to split array chunk by rule?

Tags: c#, linq

I can split an array into smaller chunks.

```
public class Item{
    public string Name {get; set;}  
    public bool IsUnique {get;set;} 
}

public static void Main()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    var source = new[] { 
        new Item { Name = "Item-1", IsUnique = true},
        new Item { Name = "Item-2", IsUnique = true},
        new Item { Name = "Item-3", IsUnique = true},
        new Item { Name = "Item-4"},
        new Item { Name = "Item-5"},
        new Item { Name = "Item-6"},
        new Item { Name = "Item-7"},
        new Item { Name = "Item-8"},
        new Item { Name = "Item-9"} 
    };

    var chunkSize = 3;

    var result = source         
        .OrderBy(a => r.Next())
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Item = x })          
        .GroupBy(s => s.Index / chunkSize)
        .Select(g => g.ToList())
        .ToList();

    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chunk: "+ (result.IndexOf(item)+1));
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        foreach(var x in item)
        {               
            Console.WriteLine(x.Item.Name);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The result is like this:

```
Chunk: 1
-----------------------------------
Item-2
Item-3
Item-8

Chunk: 2
-----------------------------------
Item-5
Item-9
Item-7

Chunk: 3
-----------------------------------
Item-6
Item-4
Item-1
```

But if `IsUniquer` property of an item is `true`, they can not be in same chunk. For example above, `Chunk-1` contains `item-2` and `item-3` .

Can I do this using linq?

UPDATE:

If chunk size is 3, only 3 item may be IsUnique=true.

Comment: Note that there is absolutely no way to do this if there are more `isUnique` elements than the number of chunks.

Comment: If chunk size is 3, only 3 item may be IsUnique=true. I updated the post

Comment: The chunk size has nothing to do with this. It is the _number_ of chunks.

Comment: Does the order of the items matter? Suppose the list isn't sorted, do you expect the items to end up in 2 single-item groups at the beginning and the next group containing 3 items, including the 3rd unique item?

Comment: Order does not matter, I am creating the random order.

Comment: Sure, but what I tried to ask is: how do you expect ordering to impact the way items end up in one group? For example, which result would you expect w/o ordering, and which result if the order of the source items is reversed? If it doesn't matter, you can always create 1-item groups for all unique items because there's always one ordering that would yield this result.

Answer (score 1):

Split your `source` array into two groups: those items which is unique and rest. Then iterate through each element in `unique` collection and take `chunkSize - 1` from `nonUnique` collection. Take a look at thhis code:

```
var unique = source.Where(x => x.IsUnique);
var nonUnique = source.Where(x => !x.IsUnique)
    .OrderBy(x => r.Next())
    .ToList();

var result = unique.Aggregate(
    (list: new List<List<Item>>(), items: nonUnique),
    (c, n) =>
    {
        var next = c.items.Take(chunkSize - 1).ToList();
        next.Add(n);

        c.items.RemoveRange(0, chunkSize - 1);
        c.list.Add(next.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToList());
        return (c.list, c.items);
    }).list;
```